# How to group by rather for date time?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Let's consider I am having following data in my table:

```
User id date time 
User1.  28-JUL-16 06:14:56 
User1.  28-JUL-16 04:12:12
User2.  28-JUL -16 05:10:45
User3.  30-JUL-16 03:10:12
```

I want to find the count of users on date wise.
Please some help on this!

Comment: What difficulty are you having - just excluding the time portion from the grouping? Are you counting distinct users, or all appearances for each user on each day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the time portion of a date using [the `trunc()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm), which defaults to converting the time part to midnight. You can then group by that.

```
with your_table (user_id, date_time) as (
  select 'User1.', to_date('28-JUL-16 06:14:56', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 'User1.', to_date('28-JUL-16 04:12:12', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 'User2.', to_date('28-JUL-16 05:10:45', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 'User3.', to_date('30-JUL-16 03:10:12', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select to_char(trunc(date_time), 'DD-MON-RR') as date_only, count(distinct user_id)
from your_table
group by trunc(date_time);

DATE_ONLY                           COUNT(DISTINCTUSER_ID)
------------------ ---------------------------------------
28-JUL-16                                                2
30-JUL-16                                                1
```

I've included `distinct` as it isn't clear if you want to count a user more than once n the same day; if you do then just remove that.

```
select to_char(trunc(date_time), 'DD-MON-RR') as date_only, count(user_id)
from your_table
group by trunc(date_time);

DATE_ONLY                                   COUNT(USER_ID)
------------------ ---------------------------------------
28-JUL-16                                                3
30-JUL-16                                                1
```